# Composing romantic pieces

Tags: harmony, composition, improvisation, romantic-period

I am a fan of the organist Wolfgang Seifen. Recently, he played a piece which fascinated me: An arabesque in the style of German romanticism. ([Hear it](https://youtu.be/apiPWhEYN2g?t=852))

Being myself interested in improvisation, I did not find good resources for composing such a piece. The sources I found where rather superficial. For merely baroque-classical harmony, there is e. g. Krüger's "Harmonielehre im Selbstudium", for Jazz the "Neue Jazz-Harmonielehre" by Sikora (German is my mother tongue), but I was not able to find a resource to being able to create a piece in a style similar to the named Arabesque.

I'm interested in resources considering the harmony of this epoque as well as those considering the rhythm or other musical aspects of composition.

Yes, I know that, experimenting in my free time, I will not by a long chalk reach the level of Prof. Seifen's skills, but this is no reason for me to completely give up my intention. Many thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: How about playing, listening and reading scores of some of the original German romanticists?  Note that some of the famous composers spent a fair amount of time copying scores as part of their study, wanting to understand why the composer made the choices he did.  So, you could copy the score for the organ piece you're crazy about, or transcribe it.

Comment: @aparente001 - I'd suggest making your comment an answer. The OP can focus on transcribing the parts that particularly catch their ear, rather than wading through lots of examples in a textbook.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS - You're welcome to, if you like.